# IP Comparison between 2 Locations

Tags: ip

can one location have more than 1 IP address? I have 2 IP addresses and need to know if they originate from the same source. Thanks

Comment: Define 'source'. There's nothing magical about an IP address. If you're getting two different IP addresses, it should be treated as two different 'sources', because they've told you (by virtue of using two different IPs) that they should be treated as different 'sources'.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing clear definitions of "location" and "source" in your question but lets go with the assumption that you mean "physical machine" for both (as it's obvious that multiple machines will have different addresses and that a single machine can change its IP address over time).

In that case, the answer is **yes**.  The operating system may bind as many IP addresses to a physical network port (and a single MAC -- the physical addressing used by Ethernet) as it wishes.

Binding multiple IP addresses was the standard way of doing "virtual web hosting" before HTTP/1.1 arrived with the "Host" header.  The provider would use DNS to map different host names to different IPs on the same network (usually the same subnet as well) and then assign all of them to the same interface.  The webserver would get address information from an incoming connection and based on the *local* IP address would know which virtual host was being accessed.

This led to a higher-than-typical use of public IP addresses but the practice is now gone with the proliferation of HTTP/1.1.

I'm not sure how Windows presents it, but Linux will present a physical interface with multiple IP addresses as multiple logical interfaces such as "eth0", "eth0:1", "eth0:2", etc.  Each logical interface has a unique IP address even though they share the same physical interface.

Answer (score 0):

One network adapter normally has only one IP address at once and a typical end user only has one network connection active, but even then the IP address can change. The user could switch from wireless to wired and back or a power outage might reset the ISP's DHCP server (assigning everyone a new IP address).

If you want to identify the user even if his IP address changes, you need to identify the user by his session id, stored in cookies. As two users can have the same IP address (a whole company could be behind a NAT), you should never rely on IP addresses for identification.

Comment: This is not true.  A single physical interface can have any number of IP addresses; they can be on the same subnet or different subnets.  It typically has only one _MAC_ address (the address Ethernet uses) though that isn't set in stone either.

Comment: I agree to the 2nd section, would cause a +1, but the 1st section is completely wrong. -1. A network adapter can have several IP addresses at one time, and the IP address can change during a browser session (depending on what you define such one to be). Even the 3rd assumption is wrong - a user can be connected over several ISPs, having a load balancer, or they can experience a forced reconnection, as it is the case with some German ISPs.

Comment: @BrianWhite: rewrote the first paragraph and reversed its conclusion. I apologise

Comment: @glglgl: rewrote the first paragraph and reversed its conclusion. I apologise

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to tell. Especially it is hard to tell if these IP addresses are from different times. Today I may have a different IP address than tomorrow.

Even they are from the same time, a load balancer im my internal equipment might send my packets over the fail-over line if the 1st one is overloaded or broken down.